# samba: how to use groups when setting Windows permissions?

Tags: samba

I'm using samba 4.6 on CentOS 7 without any fancy stuff (just the local samba server, no active directory/domain controller). One of my machines uses Windows 7.

Now I'd like to grant permissions for a file to a specific group from Windows 7 (Explorer, file properties, security tab). This works fine if I  enter "Everyone" but I can not add any other (unix) group (Windows keeps telling me "name not found").

If I change the file's group via Linux shell it also appears on Windows and I can set the permissions how I want but I'm unable to add the group.

I assume I need to instruct samba somehow to "expose" some unix groups to Windows but I failed to do so.

I tried "net rap group add ..." (no error but no visible effect either) and messed around with "net groupmap" ("NT Group ... doesn't exist in mapping DB").

In the end I don't need "unix" groups per se visible in Windows but somehow I'd like to use groups via the Windows explorer.

Comment: You would need to set up integrated groups through Samba winbind.

Comment: any pointers here? All posts I can find talk about Active Directory etc but I don't have that. Also `wbinfo --online-status` returns `BUILTIN`+`PCNAME` but `wbinfo --own-domain` lists `MYWORKGROUP`. The latter name also does not appear in `wbinfo --all-domains`. Maybe that's a problem?

Comment: @RamanSailopal: After some reading I'm not sure anymore if "winbind" is the right solution. From what I read it uses information from Active Directory/an NT4 domain and maps it to Unix concepts (e.g. users). I'm looking for the opposite direction: I want "unix groups" usable on multiple Windows clients without setting up an active directory.

Comment: You would need to set up a workgroup on Samba and then add your Windows machine to the workgroup, using Samba pdbedit to set up users and groups.